# Setting up SSL/HTTPS on Amazon S3 static site on (EU London) bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

So I can request certificates from AWS Certificate Manager, and they go through fine.

Then I go to cloudfront but it won't let me click custom SSL.

All the things I read online tell me it only works for USA North Virgina buckets? How can this be possible? Are all EU users unable to get SSL?

When I try to delete my bucket and create a North Virginia one it gives me an error "A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.".

Any other way to enable SSL on a simple static site?

EDIT:

So apparently my cloudfront says I am up, my certificate is in use so everything should be fine? But for some reason my site is still unsecured.

Comment: The bucket does not have to be in us-east-1, only ACM certificate does.

Comment: But I created a us-east-1 ACM certificate and it still doesn't work. So my buckets are alexis-drakopoulos.com and www.alexis-drakopoulos.com, my certificate for us-east-1 is alexis-drakopoulos.com and has been issued and it says "in use: Yes".

Comment: Wait a second, my cloudfront says it's enabled and issued as well, so shouldn't I have SSL/HTTPS? But when I go on my site it says unsecured.

Comment: You need to point your Route53 Alias to CF distribution

Comment: I'm using namecheap, would that work too ?

Comment: it should, https://alexis-drakopoulos.com looks good now I guess :)